# Devexpress upgrade problems (ToolTipController.BeforShow event is not working)

Tags: c#, devexpress, upgrade

### Description (Bla Bla):

I have a plan screen and this screen is the scheduler.

we were using devexpress v14 before.

We have now updated to v21.

There were some problems and we fixed them.

however, the design problems still persist.

### Codes :

In the images below, I show you the tooltip in designer background codes, some of the worker logic I use, and the scheduler in designer background codes.

### Problem :

ToolTipController is shown when the scheduler hovers over the appointment.
In the old previous version BeforeShow was working.

But now it by no means stops at the breakpoint I attached to BeforeShow.

I'm leaving the solution link on Devexpress's official page below. I applied this solution, but let me tell you why it didn't work: Because BeforeShow is never called.

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/BC3492/the-type-of-the-schedulercontrol-tooltips-has-been-changed-from-standard-to-supertip

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**We found the solution after a long struggle.**

> Hello Tim,
> Starting with version 17.1 we added the capability to display information about appointments using the Appointment Flyout element:
> Appointment Flyout
> We added this functionality to replace previous (less informative) appointment tooltips and, correspondingly, in this case custom tooltips displayed using the ToolTipController.BeforeShow event handler are disabled.
> If you need to display custom tooltips using the mentioned event handler, hide appointment flyouts by setting the SchedulerOptionsCustomization.AllowDisplayAppointmentFlyout property to false.
> I hope you will find this information helpful.

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t527648/tooltipcontroller-beforeshow-no-longer-getting-raised